# Is it worth to put a UHS micro SD in a class 10 device?

Tags: storage, sd-card, benchmarking, uhs

Here is speed test I found for Lexar x633 class 10 UHS-1

[image: Benchmark Lexar x633 class 10 UHS-1]

I'm interested in 4k Q32 and 4k. Typically, class 10 cards will reach no more than 0.1 to 0.2 MB/s. If I put a class 10 UHS-1 card in a device, which supports only class 10, will the 4K Q32 and 4K speeds remain the same, or will the speed drop?

Comment: Looks like your bottleneck is not the card - so changing it won't make a significant difference.

Comment: And what if the botteneck is the card? If I have enough cpu power and ram. Is uhs microsd hc enchanted controller faster (the one in the card) than regular class 10 card? Is UHS enchanted controller of the using device less powerful than class 10 controller. In short term - is only bus enchanted or controller is too enchanted and is device class 10 controller  able to handle uhs 4k/32DQ4k speeds bearly 1 MB/s? Someone can give a try before I purchase one and be dissapoited :D that I have give twice more money for what I do not need right now and maybe will need after hardware upgrade some day.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I`m going to try to answer my question. I think it is not worth, there is frequency difference of 4 times. UHS-1 works with 100 Mhz and Class 10 with 25 Mhz. When we do 4k/4kDQ32 we are passing multiple read/write commands over the control bus, and it is logical to exist an additional delay between these commands (summed with delay taken to transfer 4k data) in contrast when passing sequential data. So this delays will be smaller, becouse of the frequency - highter frequency, highter data in single second. The other thing is the controller in the sd card. Cheaper cards are poorly programed than the more expensive and the more expensive ones can reach up to 50% more in the benchmarks for 4k/4k32DQ. But in that way of thinking I can buy class 10 expensive if I do need, but here we are takling about 0.1 vs 0.2 MB/s, which is not worth it.

Conclusion:
For the things I`m doing I will buy cheapest 32 GB class 4 card with 0.07 MB/s 4k/32DQ4k speed(almost 3 times slower than most expensive class 10).